# Is "bask someone in something" legitimate?

Tags: phrase-usage

If I wish to say I enjoy doing something, can I say alternatively that I bask myself in doing that thing? Is such usage of "bask in" legitimate?

Comment: I think *bask in* connotes a specific kind of 'enjoy'. Also note that it's an intransitive verb. See http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bask.

Comment: Ah, so simply saying that I bask in doing something suffices? Thank you very much.

Comment: You got the phrase down, but you can't just use it for general enjoyment of an activity.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't use "bask in" to say you enjoy doing something.  "Bask in" has [two specific uses](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bask):

- To bask in the sun and its warmth and light, and
- To bask in fame, glory, or the attention of another person.

"Bask" can't be used in other contexts.  For example, you can't say "I bask in basketball."  You can, however, say "I'm still basking in the glory from our state basketball championship."